# Is there a way to open a YoutTube Link on a mobile website (iPhone) without opening the YouTube App

Tags: iphone, mobile, youtube, web

I think the answer to this is probably no, as I have been searching for days and have not run across the answer.  I have a mobile site that has links to youtube videos in `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX` format.  The links open in the iPhone Youtube app which takes the user out of Safari and is a suboptimal experience, as the user then has to re-open safari.  Is there any type of parameter to pass that would allow these video links to open in the same view that say an embedded video opens in, or a direct MP4 would open in(which allows the user to simply click done, and boom they are back on Safari)? It sucks that only iframe or embedded videos seem to allow this functionality and not links.

Answer (score 0):

From messing around with the mobile Youtube site itself, it looks like you can link to the mobile page for a particular video with this URL format: `http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX`. Visiting that URL will show the video page in Safari without launching the Youtube app.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I have an anchor tag with that format for the href, it still opens the link in the YouTube app.  Thanks for the quick replay though.

Comment: In that case, you’ll probably have to go the embed route and include the Youtube player yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution is pretty simple but elegant and it did work perfectly

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser