# How to open YouTube links in SafariController instead of the YouTube App in iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, youtube, sfsafariviewcontroller

In iOS9 i want to open a youtube channel link in **SFSafariViewController** . If My mobile not having **Youtube** Application everything Working fine . The Problem is when i install youtube application i cant go forward because manually added activitiIndicator View . problem  is Mention in the Image.

NOTE: i have a solution  checking application exist or not. if Application exists remove the Activity view.

This Problem is only for **YOUTUBE** Links . Other links like Facebook , Instagram are working fine.

Can anyone give me the Better Solution .

**NOTE:** i haven't find solution From this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512735/is-there-a-way-to-open-a-youttube-link-on-a-mobile-website-iphone-without-open)

**EDITED:** activity view added Manually.

[image]

Comment: is the activity indicator over the alert ?

Comment: Activity indicator showing on window. until it remove no user interaction happens .

Comment: this probably looks a bug, report to apple.

Comment: @Shubhank The activity indicator is manually implemented , its not a bug

Comment: @AtWork oh, ok. i thought the `SFSafariViewController` was probably coming inbuilt with it.

Comment: activity view added Manually.